# Call a method from a view controller that is contained in a scrollView, that is contained in a view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8

i have this issue I have a ViewController in which i have a scrollView, this  scrollView have 3 view controllers inside, so from a inner view controller contained in the scroll view, i want to call a method from the rootViewController to scroll between the child controllers .

Root View -> ScrollView -> 3 Child View Controllers (call method)

Do somebody know how can i achieve this?

Comment: Do you have the instance of ChildViewControllers in RootView. If not declare all viewController in RootView. You can use this instance to call the method.

Comment: @New16 I think it would be the other way around. Each instance of child view controller should have a weak reference to the parent/root view controller to call a method on it.